# JNI load jar with dependencies

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jnienv

I am trying to load the following java class in my C++ program using JNI:

```
package helloWorld;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class HelloWorld{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
    public static int square(int input){
        int output = input * input;
        return output;
    }
    public static int power(int input, int exponent){
        int output,i;
        output=1;
        for(i=0;i<exponent;i++){
            output *= input;
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

It depends on log4j-1.2.16.jar

Here is my C++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "../Header/jni.h"

JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM **jvm)
{
    char * classPath = (char *) "-Djava.class.path=HelloWorld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar";
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVMInitArgs args;
    JavaVMOption options[2];
    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    args.nOptions = 1;
    options[0].optionString = classPath;
    options[1].optionString = "-verbose";
    args.options = options;
    args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
    int rv;
    rv = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &args);
    if (rv < 0 || !env)
        printf("Unable to Launch JVM %d\n",rv);
    else
        printf("Launched JVM! :)\n");
    return env;
}

void invoke_class(JNIEnv* env)
{
    jclass hello_world_class;
    jmethodID main_method;
    jmethodID square_method;
    jmethodID power_method;
    jint number=20;
    jint exponent=3;

    hello_world_class = env->FindClass("helloWorld/HelloWorld");

    if(hello_world_class == NULL){
        if(env->ExceptionOccurred()){
            env->ExceptionDescribe();
        }
        printf("Class not found.");
    }
    else{
        main_method = env->GetStaticMethodID(hello_world_class, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
        square_method = env->GetStaticMethodID(hello_world_class, "square", "(I)I");
        power_method = env->GetStaticMethodID(hello_world_class, "power", "(II)I");
        env->CallStaticVoidMethod(hello_world_class, main_method, NULL);
        printf("%d squared is %d\n", number,
                env->CallStaticIntMethod(hello_world_class, square_method, number));
        printf("%d raised to the %d power is %d\n", number, exponent,
                env->CallStaticIntMethod(hello_world_class, power_method, number, exponent));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    env = create_vm(&jvm);
    if(env == NULL)
        return 1;
    invoke_class(env);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I have placed HelloWorld.jar in the root folder of my C++ application. When it tries to load hello_world_class, the following exeception is thrown:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at helloWorld.HelloWorld.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:7)
```

JNI doesn't find the log4j dependency because it is not inside HelloWorld.jar. Ive tried to place it on a lib folder and in the same folder that HelloWorld.jar but it didn't work. Where do I need to place the log4j.jar so JNI can regonize it and load it?

Thank you very much, im a newbie on jni so please be clear in your answers. Ive been at this error the whole day T.T

Comment: If it's C++ code, why did you tag C?

Comment: Sorry, removed the tag.

Comment: You're specifying the class part explicitly already; why not list both `jar`s?

Comment: @AlanStokes do you mean declaring another classPath with log4j jar path? But would jni understand that it is a dependency of HelloWorld.jar? How would i link it as a dependency to HelloWorld?

Comment: `-Djava.class.path=foo.jar;baz.jar` (Or use : not ; on Linux.) It doesn't care about dependencies, it just wants to know where to look for each class as it needs it.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to pass location of `JAR` files inside options. You can do something like this:

```
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=./target:../target:./jar:./jar/log4j-api-2.12.1.jar:./jar/log4j-core-2.12.1.jar";
```

Remember that you will probably also need `log4j2.xml` (in case of `log4j-2.12.1`). To make sure your config file is discoverable, add directory (with the file) to class path as well.

You can find full sample code here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo060